# double click on jlist in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlist, mouselistener

I want select item in list by mouse. I found this code but it didn't work.

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            System.out.println("Double clicked on Item " + index);
         }
    }
};
list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Comment: "*it didn't work*" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);  this gives error, it can't see mouseListener

Comment: "*this gives error*" is neither a valid Java compiler error nor a valid Java Exception.

Comment: Post your SSCCE demonstrating the problem. Search the forum or web if you don't know what a SSCCE is.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, Sample Application it works fine !!!!!!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class calc {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String labels[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" };
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selecting JList");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JList jlist = new JList(labels);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
    frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        JList theList = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
          int index = theList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
          if (index >= 0) {
            Object o = theList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
            System.out.println("Double-clicked on: " + o.toString());
          }
        }
      }
    };
    jlist.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

    frame.setSize(350, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: use this  JList list = (JList)evt.getSource(); before If condition

Comment: i already have list, so i don't need first two line i guess, but other codes give "illegal start of expression" error

Comment: `i already have list, so i don't need first two line i guess` - the better way to write a listener is to use the getSource() method. Your listener should not depend on a class variable.

Comment: Plesae Dont Debug the code, then you won't get the Click Count value 2